# How to append time of creation to a file and to all WikiLinks instances where appear inside a text?

Tags: command-line, python, shell-script, batch-rename

I'm using Obsidian as a zettlekasten app. I have a vault of 1000+ `.md` files with my notes. Some of them are linked inside other notes via wiki links. I want to change all my `.md` file's name by appending to the end the time of creation, but at the same time I want all my internal links to update where it appears. In Obsidian app I have to change the file manually since this is the only way to get updated links. I can't do externally, because Obsidinan will not update the wikilinks.

**I can append the time creation to multiple files via Total Commander, but I can't update file names inside a text.**

Assuming I have the following 3 files:

```
file1.md
- this is the text of file1 where I link [[file2]] and [[file3]]

file2.md
 - this is the text of file2 where I link [[file1]] and [[file3]]

file3.md
 - this is the text of file3 where I link [[file1]] and [[file2]]
```

After the renaming I have:

```
file1 202104081851.md
- this is the text of file1 where I link [[file2]] and [[file3]]

file2 202104081852.md
- this is the text of file2 where I link [[file1 ]] and [[file3 ]]

file3 202104081853.md
- this is the text of file3 where I link [[file1]] and [[file2]]
```

Is any script/ software you know to bulk change also the wikilinks? I'm on Windows 10, I have `python` installed and `npm`

Comment: Hi, and about your line in yours files. All file names are without extension, and with thus layout string "[[]]": `[[string_file_name_without_extension]]`?

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe, yes they are without extension in wikilinks. This is the way Obsidian is making wikilins. I saw some extensions for VS Code which are inserting the extension. This is not the case for Obsidian, though.

Comment: I lost my pendrive with this answer (and more  others too) and I’ll rewrite this again tomorrow for you.

Comment: You also need replace `[[File1]]` to `[[File1 202104081851]]` in each line?

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe Yes. Those are wiki links that has to correspond to the newly renamed file.